# Is it possibile to add a \vrule between the two parts of a gcard?

Tags: rules, fun, cards

I'm writing some greetings cards using the `gcard` package.

All works well, but I don't want to fold the sheet twice to make a card, I'd prefer to print it twice, double-sided, and then cut it in the middle with a cutter.

I'm trying to put a `\vrule` between the two parts of the card to have a guide for the cutting, but I'm not managing to do it.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{gcard}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontcover}
        \centering 
        \huge
        \textit{I love ducks!}
    \end{frontcover}

    \centering \vline height \paperheight

    \begin{insideright}
        \begin{center} 
            \Huge
            \textit{Quack!}
        \end{center}
    \end{insideright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need this line in the middle of the previous sheet:

[image]

Comment: I would simply load tikz and use `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw(current page.north)--(current page.south);`. Easier than trying to figure out where textpos places its boxes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's works perfectly, thank you! If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply load `tikz` and use

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw(current page.north)--(current page.south);
```

Easier than trying to figure out where `textpos` places its boxes:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{gcard}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontcover}
    \centering
    \huge
    \textit{I love ducks!}
\end{frontcover}
\begin{insideright}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge
        \textit{Quack!}
    \end{center}
\end{insideright}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw(current page.north)--(current page.south);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to move the `tikz` code at the end. Otherwise, `textpos` gives a warning.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{gcard,multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vrule height0pt depth \textheight width 0pt
    \begin{frontcover}
        \centering 
        \huge
        \textit{I love ducks!}
    \end{frontcover}

\begin{insideright}
        \begin{center} 
            \Huge
            \textit{Quack!}
        \end{center}
    \end{insideright}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to modify the size of the page, I prefer Ulrike's answer...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sorry, I missed out the landscape option. I shall edit to include it.